# Is there a way for a derived type to assign a value to its parent's element in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's say I have the following schema:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="animals" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="animals">

<xs:complexType name="AnimalType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="legs" xml:base="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DogType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="furColor" xml:base="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BirdType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="canFly" xml:base="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Let's assume that all dogs have 4 legs and all birds have 2 legs. Is it possible to set those values as default, so elements could be created without specifying them?

```
<!--a black dog with 4 legs-->
<dog>
    <furColor>black</furColor>
</dog>

<!--a flightless bird with 2 legs-->
<bird>
    <canFly>false</canFly>
</bird>
```

If not, is it at least possible to modify restrictions of parent's elements, to make creation of e.g. a five-legged dog impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to have an implicit default **element** `legs`. But it is possible to modify the types which make a five-legged dog invalid by restricting the `AnimalType` first with respect to `legs` and then extend that restricted type:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnimalType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="legs" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AnimalWith2LegsType" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="legs">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                            <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AnimalWith4LegsType" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="legs">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
                            <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="DogType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalWith4LegsType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="furColor" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BirdType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AnimalWith2LegsType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="canFly" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="animals">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="dog" type="DogType"/>
            <xs:element name="bird" type="BirdType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This way instances of this schema are forced to specify the `legs` element with the specified fixed value:

```
<dog>
    <legs>4</legs>
    <furColor>black</furColor>
</dog>

<bird>
    <legs>2</legs>
    <canFly>false</canFly>
</bird>
```

---

If `legs` are specified as **attribute** it is indeed possible to have an implicit number of legs. Just change the definition of `AnimalType`, `AnimalWith2LegsType` and `AnimalWith4LegsType` to:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnimalType" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="legs" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AnimalWith2LegsType" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="legs" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" fixed="2" use="optional"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AnimalWith4LegsType" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AnimalType">
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="legs" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" fixed="4" use="optional"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now you can have valid instances containing:

```
<dog legs="4">
    <furColor>black</furColor>
</dog>

<bird legs="2">
    <canFly>false</canFly>
</bird>
```

and

```
<dog>
    <furColor>black</furColor>
</dog>

<bird>
    <canFly>false</canFly>
</bird>
```

Unless you do not intend to specify multiple sets of legs (for [caterpillars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar) maybe?) you will want to model `legs` as attribute to achieve what you want.